# Issues using SQL Server's BCP utility to insert data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have what should be a simple task: using `ISQL`, obtain data from a Sybase database and use the `BCP` utility to insert the resulting CSV file into a table in a SQL Server database.

I've tried a number of permutations of quoted/unquoted data, format files, etc., but BCP continues to throw the same error:

> Starting copy...
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0

The incoming data file consists of nine columns:

```
"he1aixp9-2","srcpdb",20150701,20150731,"N","IBM  UDB","udbxsrcp_sby",202025,196358
```

I used the `BCP` utility to generate a format file for the table in question using the suggested defaults for each column:

```
11.0
9
1       SQLCHAR             2       32      ","    1     ID_ETY_SVR                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             2       32      ","    2     ID_ETY_DB                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLDATE             1       3       ","    3     DT_SMPL_BEG                              ""
4       SQLDATE             1       3       ","    4     DT_SMPL_END                              ""
5       SQLCHAR             2       1       ","    5     FLAG_DEL                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             2       64      ","    6     TYPE_DB                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             2       32      ","    7     ID_ETY_HOST                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLBIGINT           1       8       ","    8     ID_ETY_SPACE_TOTAL                       ""
9       SQLBIGINT           1       8       ""     9     ID_ETY_SPACE_USED                        ""
```

I'm using the following command line to invoke the process:

```
"\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp" [table_to_load] in [Data File to be loaded] -S[server] -[database] -T -fDBLoad.fmt
```

So far I've done the following:

- Spent hours searching the web and reading on-line documentation from MS.
- Run the data through a filter to ensure that any leading/trailing spaces were removed.
- Ensured that all character columns are quoted (ISQL is no help here, and I can't use the PowerShell extensions).
- Ensured that all rows have the correct number of columns.
- Tried to load a one-line test file, selectively shortening each column's data to a single byte (character only) to ensure that no field is really too long (I've checked the table definition and they are not).
- Ensured that the Date format used, "YYYYMMDD" is to the DB's liking.

This is such a trivial issue, and yet I cannot get `BCP` to load data.

Comment: Can you leave just one line in your data file and try to import that? Do you get the error? If so try putting some dummy data into the file and import that. If not keep adding lines back till you find the row with the error.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Same issue.

Comment: So no matter what you put in the file, even a manually generated file with dummy data, you get the same error?

Comment: Not dummy data, no. I use either head -x or tail -x to extract one or more lines of actual data. The example data I showed in the original posting was extracted in that manner. Even with that data, I've selectively shortened column data to ensure that it did not exceed the defined column width: "~", for instance for character data, 0 for numeric data.

Comment: Your format file describes a binary file, but you are trying to import a text based file. Do the following. Export a format file for the text format `-c` instead of native `-n` and use `-t,` for comma delimiting. Next edit the format file by hand to match your data. You may be better off creating an XML format file by hand. see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx